# Is "two different ones" grammatically correct?

Tags: phrase-choice

I've seen this phrase in several IT-related texts:

> You'd have to have them in the same repo instead of two different ones.

> As a result, you end up with a single commit instead of two different ones.

Such a words combination like "two different ones", "four different ones" sounds awkward to me. It it actually okay, or should it be rephrased? How exactly?

Comment: The word *different* adds no meaning here since you won't have two repos that are the same repo. But it does add emphasis, so it gets a pass. Plus, IT writing is notoriously, um, inelegant with slang and jargon, so what becomes common becomes acceptable as the norm.

Comment: For the most useful answer, you might see if you can figure out why it sounds awkward to you. It's a common usage.

Comment: @AndyBonner I just perceive "one" and "two" as numbers, although I know "one" is not actually a number in this case.

Comment: When "one" is used the way it is in your example sentences, it's not a number but something called an *indefinite pronoun*. Reference: https://www.houstonisd.org/cms/lib2/TX01001591/Centricity/Domain/26063/Indefinite%20Pronoun%20Study%20Guide.pdf